# short circuit in a ir sensor

Tags: infrared, short-circuit

I am working on a IR sensor and i noticed that there was a short circuit.

The voltage regulator 7805 output was getting clamped to 4v.

And on my transmitter side i have connected 150 ohms resistance in series with transmitter led.

So then i changed resistor to 1k ohms and now the circuit works fine and there is no voltage clamp at output of 7805.But still i dint understand what was the problem.

Why the circuit was getting short with 150ohms.

I also calculated current values for both resistance values

R=150ohms------i=33mA

R=1kohms-------i=5mA

I know this question is very basic but can any one tell me whats the reason??

[image]

Comment: The little (78L05) voltage regulators are good to ~100mA. Is there some other load on the circuit besides the 150 ohm resistor?  What's your input voltage?

Comment: Schematics!!! What input voltage on your 7805, what type or IR sensor, how does the transmitter side look. Seriously, if you want help, help us to help you

Comment: Clamped to 4V? In case of short circuit you should see 0V, wherever it was that you measured the voltage.

Comment: Is pin 4 of the LM358 floating or connected to ground?

Comment: sorry it is connected to ground!!

Comment: My guess is it wasn't actually a 150 ohm resistor. Maybe 15 or something. (I'm also guessing it got hot - did any components get hot?)

Comment: I have checked it and  multimeter reads 150 ohm.But yes it was getting a bit hot.

Comment: Also, FYI, your current calculations are wrong. They do not take into account the voltage across the IR diode. Anyway... to solve the problem, try measuring the voltage across the 150 ohm resistor while it is in the circuit, if it reads as 5v or 0v then there is your problem. Similarly, try replacing the 15 ohm resistor and IR transmitter with say a 220 ohm resistor, and see if that also pulls the voltage down from 5v. With determination, trial and error (which you seem to be well on the way with), you can figure it out :)

Comment: Are you using a new 9v battery?  When your circuit seems loaded down (with the 150 ohm in place) check your battery voltage.  Standard 9v "transistor" batteries are not great at supplying high currents, especially if it is a non-alkaline type.

Answer (score 2):

A 9V battery as input to an 7805 regulator will work only for a very short time and under a very light load. (The input to an 7805 must be >7 or >8 V, depending on the manufacturer. A 9V abttery might be called '9V', but its voltage drops quickly. )

With the 150 Ohm, your circuit did not qualify as 'very light load'. With 1k it apparently does, but it will not do so for a long time. Better use a 9-12V DC wall wart.

Oh, and while you are at it: add a 100nF capacitor at the output of the 7805, and a >= 10uF capacitor at the input (mind the polarity).